# Combinatorial proof for the identity $\binom{n}{2} = \binom{k}{2} + k(n-k)+ \binom{n-k}{2}$

Tags: combinatorics

Use the factorial definition of $\binom{m}{r}$ to verify that
$$\binom{n}{2} = \binom{k}{2} + k(n-k)+ \binom{n-k}{2}, \quad 1 \leq k \leq n$$
Also, give a combinatorial argument for the validity of this identity.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we wish to select two people from a group of $n$ people, of whom $k$ are women.  We can choose these people in $\binom{n}{2}$ ways.  There are three possibilities:

1. We choose two women, which can be done in $\binom{k}{2}$ ways.
2. We choose two men, which can be done in $\binom{n - k}{2}$ ways.
3. We choose one woman and one man, which can be done in $k(n - k)$ ways.

Adding the three disjoint cases gives us our total.